# How can I express a function contract in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that can return `undefined` when its argument is `undefined`, otherwise it always returns a value derived from its argument. For example:

```
function triple(value?: number) : number | undefined {
  return value && value * 3;
}
```

Now when I use this function, I *know*  that it won't return `undefined` when I supply a parameter:

```
const x = 3;
const tripleValue : number = triple(x);
```

Unsurprisingly, TypeScript gives me `TS2322: Type 'number|undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Is there any way I can tell TypeScript that `triple` *never* returns `undefined` when its argument is defined?

I'm using TypeScript 3.4.5 with `strictNullChecks`.

To reproduce, see this [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20triple(value%3F%3A%20number)%20%3A%20number%20%7C%20undefined%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20value%20%26%26%20value%20*%203%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%20%3D%203%3B%0D%0Aconst%20tripleValue%20%3A%20number%20%3D%20triple(x)%3B). Make sure to click *Options* and check `strictNullChecks`.

Comment: Write the two different behaviours as [overloads](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

Comment: @jonrsharpe That seems to be the right solution. Care to post it as an answer? I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this myself, as @jonrsharpe hasn't.

The solution (as per @jonrsharpe's comment) is to create two signatures for the function, using [overloads](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).
This lets you have two or more different signatures for the same function implementation.

To express that the function will always return a number when its argument is a number, but may return `undefined` when its argument is `undefined`, we need two different signatures:

```
function triple(value : number) : number;
function triple(value?: number) : number | undefined {
    return value && value * 3;
}
```

This lets me use the function without TSC complaining:

```
const x = 3;
const tripleValue : number = triple(x);
```

See the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20triple(value%3A%20number)%3A%20number%3B%0D%0Afunction%20triple(value%3F%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7C%20undefined%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20value%20%26%26%20value%20*%203%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%20%3D%203%3B%0D%0Aconst%20tripleValue%20%3A%20number%20%3D%20triple(x)%3B) for demonstration, remember to enable `strictNullChecks` under *Options*.